# How to solve matrix equation $AX+XB=C$ for $X$

Tags: matrices

How does one solve the matrix equation $AX+XB=C$ for $X$?
It doesn't seem too difficult. I tried many times but failed.

I'm an adult student... I am now vexed about Gilbert Strang - An Introduction to Linear Algebra.
I don't even understand a single word in Wikipedia: [Sylvester equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation). If you have ever use some nice workable materials or lecture notes? You can generously upload and share the links of the lecture notes and assignments. Different subjects/ topics are welcome, as long as you deem they are nice and workable.

The problem origins from a system of diff equation, using undetermined coefficients (matrix) to find the particular solution. Try $y_p=X\begin{pmatrix}   e^{\alpha t} \\ e^{\beta t} \end{pmatrix}$

$\dot{y}+Ay=C\begin{pmatrix} e^{\alpha t} \\ e^{\beta t}\end{pmatrix}$

$\dot{y_p}=X\begin{pmatrix} \alpha & 0 \\ 0 & \beta \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}e^{\alpha t} \\ e^{\beta t}\end{pmatrix}$

substitute $\dot{y_p}$ and $y_p$ into the original differential equation..

$X\begin{pmatrix} \alpha & 0 \\ 0 & \beta \end{pmatrix}+AX=C$

Comment: What you have there is a [Sylvester equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation) for which many solution methods are known.

Comment: Are in interested in solving the matrix equation to solve the differential equation, or in its own right?

Comment: I think this question was asked here on math.SE before, but I can't find the link.

Comment: "I don't even understand a single word in Wikipedia" - fine... do you at least know what a Kronecker product is? Or, better yet, what part of the Wiki article do you not understand?

Comment: @JenniferDylan: I think the closest thing is this, but it's not exactly a duplicate, since it has no free term: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39906/solving-a-matrix-equation-ax-xb-in-a-cas

Comment: It seems I'm seriously incapable. It is better to suggest me some materials or books rather than just give a solution to my problem. I’d like to contact J.M. also...

Answer (score 2):

The  matrix equation that prompted this post, $$X\begin{pmatrix} \alpha & 0 \\ 0 & \beta \end{pmatrix}+AX=C,$$ actually has a very easy solution.

Let $X$ and $C$ have columns $X_1,X_2$ and $C_1,C_2$, respectively. Then $$X_1=(A+\alpha I)^{-1}C_1,X_2=(A+\beta I)^{-1}C_2.$$

**Footnote**

A nice feature of this solution is that the condition for the existence and uniqueness of a solution to a Sylvester Equation is self evident in this simple case :-

$A$ and $-B$ must have no common eigenvalue.

Answer (score 1):

It seems $AX+XB=[A,I_1]X[I_2,B]^T$, where $I_1$ and $I_2$ are identity matrices and subscript 'T' is transpose of a matrix. Thus, the problem becomes how to solve $[A,I_1]X[I_2,B]^T = C $. Obviously, $X=[A,I_1]^\dagger C {[I_2,B]^T}^\dagger$, where subscript '$\dagger$' means the Pseudo-inverse.

Comment: This is incorrect. $AX+XB$ is $[A,I]\begin{bmatrix}X\\ &X\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}I\\ B\end{bmatrix}$, not $[A,I]X[I,B]^T$. Note that $[A,I]X$ is not a legitimate matrix product, as $[A,I]$ has $2n$ columns but $X$ has $n$ rows.

Comment: Yeah, I made a mistake. Thank you for your pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

Use the superoperator formalism:
$$
AXB=C \mapsto ( {B}^T\otimes A)\text{vec} X =  C
$$
(see [here](http://www.fil.ion.ucl.ac.uk/~jdaunize/docs/Kronecker.pdf) for a definition of $\text{vec}(X)\;$ and here for more information: [Kronecker product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product#Matrix_equations))

Rewrite your equation (using $AXB\to (B^T\otimes A) \text{vec}\;X$) to
$$
AX+XB=C  \to  (1\otimes A)\text{vec}\;X + (B^T\otimes 1)\text{vec}\;X=\text{vec}\;C\\
\text{vec}\;X=\left((1\otimes A) + (B^T\otimes 1)\right)^{-1}\text{vec}\;C,
$$
assuming that the last inverse exists...