# solving for matrix algebra equation

Tags: linear-algebra

How do you solve :$$AX+BXC=D$$ for $X$ where all of them are 2by 2 matrices?

Comment: See [homework](https://www.reddit.com/r/cheatatmathhomework/comments/8drek2/solve_for_2x2_matrix_x_axbxcd/). See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186598/how-to-solve-matrix-equation-axxb-c-for-x) and related ones.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: I know it is related to Sylvester equation, I want to fist understand Sylvester equation, I.e when does it have roots. And then I want to know how it is related to Sylvester equation.

Comment: @user42493 What do you mean by "stalk water equation"?

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is as follows: with the [vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)) operator, we can rewrite the equation as 
$$
AX + BXC = D \implies
[(I \otimes A) + (C^T \otimes B)]\operatorname{vec} = \operatorname{vec}(D)
$$