# Isolating matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

I have a matrix equation reading:
$$S_{Z} T-T S_{Z}=0$$
Is it possible to isolate $T$, assuming all matrices are invertible?

Comment: It's a Sylvester equation, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186598/how-to-solve-matrix-equation-axxb-c-for-x

Comment: Thank you for the reference